# What happens here when the Second Law of Thermodynamics doesn't hold true?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, entropy, arrow-of-time

> In the 1920s, theoretical physicists, most notably Albert Einstein, considered the possibility of a cyclic model for the universe as an (everlasting) alternative to the model of an expanding universe. However, work by Richard C. Tolman in 1934 showed that these early attempts **failed because of the cyclic problem; according to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, entropy can only increase**.

The snippet of this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model) article mentions why the cyclic model failed by virtue of the *Second Law of Thermodynamics*. In this context, do we need to be assured that the law certainly needs to hold?

To elaborate, is it **hypothetically** possible that on such a scale the *Second Law* necessarily may **not** hold true?

Comment: You would be interested to read Sean Carroll's book on the direction of the arrow of time, [From Eternity to Here](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/eternitytohere/).

Comment: I haven't accessed the book yet but encountered this amazing video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMaTyg8wR4Y) on the site mentioned by @rob

Comment: What evidence do we have that universe oscillations have happened?

Comment: I don't assert that the Oscillatory Universe Model is necessarily the correct model, all I was interested  to know are the underpinnings of various scientific theories, one of them being mentioned in the above question. Therefore the tag "Thought Experiment" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second law essentially just says the most likely thing that can happen will happen. If this law is violated for the universe then there would need to be some sort of external influence that makes this not the case. In other words, treating the universe as an entire system, it couldn't be a closed system so that something external could lower the entropy of the universe

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question was "is it known that the Second Law holds in this context?" and this answer amounts to "yes, it holds because if it didn't hold it would be violated."

Comment: @benrg I think what this answer is saying is that Second Law of Thermodynamics is like '1 + 1 = 2'.

Comment: @Ibraheem Moosa The obvious argument for the Second Law goes through just as well if you reverse the direction of time, but the conclusion is false in that case. If your response to that is "it's different because the universe was smaller in the past and it's bigger in the future", then why is it so obvious that entropy won't decrease when the universe shrinks in the future, as it does in a cyclic model? In a model that's specifically constructed to be time symmetric, why *must* the Second Law break that symmetry? That's the question.

Comment: @benrg The really interesting question is why entropy was low in the early universe.  I do not think the second law says anything about what happens if you reverse time.

Comment: @benrg I think you misunderstand my answer. The OP asked about the second law not holding for the universe. I'm saying it wouldn't hold if our universe was not a closed system and something external was lowering the entropy. I'm talking about what must be true in order for this to happen. I'm not making that circular argument you say I'm making. I'm just saying what must be true in order for the entropy to decrease.

Comment: @benrg  time reversal is not possible within the existing theory of special relativity and the standard model of particle physics see  my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123347/why-do-we-remember-the-past-but-not-the-future/123367#123367